# Is it compulsory to disable interrupts on hardware after entering interrupt handler?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt, device-driver, interrupt-handling

Hardware raised an interrupt, cpu invoked registered interrupt handler on IRQ line.

In my device driver, is it compulsory to disable interrupts after I enter the handler and re-enable them after I finish required processing?

Or is it okay if we just clear the required interrupt status register without disabling and re-enabling them after the interrupt handler is invoked?

What is the correct procedure, and is this kind of handling architecture specific (x86, ARM)?

Answer (score 0):

As your IRQ handler is called from a context where further interrupts are already disabled, you don't really need to worry about disabling and re-enabling them. You can just clear the flag, do some quick work, schedule a work queue to do further works and return from the handler. And leave the enabling/disabling part to the kernel